# Threading in Python 3: Spawning a new thread for a specific process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

So I've used a bit of threading in python 2.6, but I'm confused how to do it in python 3, and it's been a while. Basically, I have a function that I pass 2 variables. I want to thread that function so that every time it's called, it creates a new thread instance, and when it finishes, the thread closes. It shouldn't be that difficult, but for some reason, after reading a ton of documentation, I can't seem to figure it out. Here's an example. 
```

```
def accept_connection(clientsocket, addr):
    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))  #some serverside debugging output
    msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)   #recieve a message from the client
    ClientAppend = str(addr) + str(msg, 'ascii')
    Clients.append(ClientAppend)
    print(Clients)


accept_connection(clientsocket, addr)
```

In case it's unclear, I want the accept_connection() function to be threaded, so that I can accept multiple connections at once and they aren't denied because one is already being processed. I'm not really sure how to do this, and I appreciate any and all help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're looking for has already been nicely described in this [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_server_client_file_transfer.php). You want to look into **multithread tcp file transfer on localhost**.

They have a nice tutorial from scratch which you can use [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_server_client.php).

They have a five part tutorial with really simple examples which are well explained. I feel the tutorial would explain much better than I could.